# Tabulator - How can I delete a row from JSON file?

Tags: json, delete-row, tabulator

I am using Tabulator to create a table.  I import information from `JSON` file using `ajaxURL: "test.json"`.  Data all loads fine.  I have created a form to enter data into.  When submitted, it goes to a `PHP` file that processes the data (decodes `test.json,` adds form data, encodes to `json`).  Everything works fine until I try to implement a way of deleting.  I have tried a few ways and none of them work.  One way would create nested arrays within my `json` array and Tabulator will not read that.  I want to be able to click the buttonCross in my Delete column and delete the row from the table and from the `JSON` file.

Is there anyway do delete `JSON` file elements without nesting arrays?

tabulator.html

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name">
        Description:
        <input type="text" name="descript">
        <br><br>
        Latitude:
        <input type="text" name="lat">                
        Longitude:
        <input type="text" name="lon">
        <br><br>
        Start Date/Time:
        <input type="date" name="startDate">
        <input type="time" name="startTime">
        <br><br>
        End Date/Time:
        <input type="date" name="endDate">
        <input type="time" name="endTime">
        <br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="deleteStatus" value="">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>

//later in the file

columns:[                 //define the table columns
                {title:"Delete", field:"deleteStatus", formatter:"buttonCross", width:50, align:"center", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
                    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')) {
                        cell.setValue("delete");
                        var row = cell.getRow();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'process.php',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: {row},
                        });
                    }
                }},
```

process.php

```
<?php

$myFile = "test.json";
$arr_data = array(); // create empty array
$time = date("YmdHis");

try
{
    //Get form data
    $formdata = array(
        'id'=> $time,
        'deleteStatus'=> $_POST['deleteStatus'],
        'name'=> $_POST['name'],
        'descript'=> $_POST['descript'],
        'lat'=> $_POST['lat'],
        'lon'=> $_POST['lon'],
        'startDate'=> $_POST['startDate'],
        'startTime'=> $_POST['startTime'],
        'endDate'=> $_POST['endDate'],
        'endTime'=> $_POST['endTime'],
    );

    //Get data from existing json file
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

    // converts json data into array
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    // Push user data to array
    array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

    foreach($arr_data as $elementKey => $element) {
        foreach($element as $valueKey => $value) {
            if($valueKey == 'deleteStatus' && $value == 'delete'){
                //delete this particular object from the $array
                unset($arr_data[$elementKey]);
            } 
        }
    }

    //Convert updated array to JSON
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    //write json data into data.json file
    if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
        header("Refresh:0; url = tabulator.html");
    }
    else 
        echo "error";

}
catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: tabulator has API for manipulating rows. Show us your code so we can understand what is going on

Comment: Edited my post with some of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/update#addrow) you need to call an API ( like node.js) to which deletes form the json file

```
table.deleteRow(15)
.then(function(){
    //Call your api to delete from JSON file 
})
.catch(function(error){
    //handle error deleting row
});

row.delete()
.then(function(){
    //run code after row has been deleted
})
.catch(function(error){
    //handle error deleting row
});
```

Comment: I ended up changing my code to use a MySQL database and then kick out the JSON file.  Seems to work better.  Thank you for answering all my questions on Tabulator.